# Qual a diferença entre métodos do Controller e do Helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, orientação-a-objetos, arquitetura-de-software

Dúvida arquitetural e conceitual:

Possuo um *model* `Item` que possuí atributos `nome_ptbr` e `nome_en`.

Fiz o seguinte método:

```
def display_nome
  nome_ptbr || nome_en
end
```

Onde devo colocar esses métodos, no *controller* ou no *helper*? Qual a diferença entre um e outro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Helpers** existem para serem usados pelas **views**.

Se este método for usado somente pelas views, escreva-o no helper.

Se ele foi pensado para ser usado na aplicação, faça-o no **model** se precisar dele em mais de um controller, ou faça-o no **controller** se ele for específico de um controlador.

[Veja esta pergunta do SO-en](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887319/common-method-in-model-and-helper).